# How to add Dyanmic Numpy Array field in Django Models

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, django-models

I wanted to add the numpy array as a field of my Django models using Django's default db.sqlite database. The "ArrayField" is not available with db.sqlite. Is there any option . Please Answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can't save array inside sqlite database. all you can do is convert your array in string with comma saparator . and after data fatch again do reverse process and convert it into array.

Ex: a=[1,11,2] to a= "1,11,2"

after data fatch convert to orginal array with split function.